# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot be booted

Tags: boot, system-installation, asus

Since I used to work with Windows 10 for years​, so, I decided to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, but the dual boot and even installing Ubuntu without Windows has brought me about unprecedented hardship, that neither me nor a lot of experienced​ people in Linux were able to resolve.

My system is a ASUS K550VX, 16 GB RAM, Intel CORE i7 CPU, and NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 950M Graphic Card.

Firstly, for installing Ubuntu alongside Windows, I separated a 100GB Space out of my disk and divided it into three partitions (a 500MB /boot with Ext4 format, a 16GB swap area and the rest as /home with Ext4 format). After installing Ubuntu and system start-up, it jumped to GNU GRUB purple screen to choose the OS. By choosing Windows, the screen faded out to black and then returned to the same page (GNU GRUB). By choosing Ubuntu, it led me to a black screen with some white codes being written on it, eventually showing the message of: "unable to run on a non-Dell system"!

Afterwards I decided to install Ubuntu as the sole OS of my computer. However, the same error for Ubuntu (non-Dell system) appears again. 
I have also tried Boot-Disk-Repair to fix Grub problems but it didn't work either (it's pending for ever, showing the message of: "this may require several minutes", with a bar swinging back and forth).

Some experienced people in Linux told me that tuning BIOS settings and secure boot might resolve the issue; however, all the attempts proved to be futile. 
I really need this OS as soon as possible to get my works through.

Comment: From where did you download your Ubuntu install image ?

Comment: It seems that you downloaded/copied Ubuntu ISO that is intended for Dell PCs only. Try downloading from Ubuntu's official site.

Comment: You mention a /boot, /home & swap partitions in your description, but skip the most important / partition.  This may have been an typo or omission, but that install would not have been allowed as you describe it.  */boot stores your kernels & files needed to boot, but system binaries go in /bin, /sbin etc that had nowhere to go...  (fyi: swap partition isn't needed for 18.04)*

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a bootable Ubuntu USB stick on an Ubuntu or Windows or Apple computer. See https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 for a step by step tutorial. DOWNLOAD ONLY OFFICIAL UBUNTU IMAGES (e.g. from here https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.)
2. Check the bios of your machine to ensure that it boots in UEFI mode (not in legacy mode), virtualization is on, and everything is OK.
3. Install Ubuntu from the Ubuntu USB stick. See https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0.
4. Follow the instructions. The installation should be straight forward.